# Document is scrolled to the slick carousel on window resize at responsive breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I've got the following slick initialization code. Basically these are two synced blocks:

1. the first is the content carousel showing only one block at a time.
2. the second is a menu carousel showing several options at a time.

   ```
   this.slick1 = $('.slider-content1').slick({
       arrows: false,
       asNavFor: '.carousel-menu1',
       adaptiveHeight: true,
       fade: true,
       speed: 1100
   });
   this.slick2 = $('.carousel-menu1').slick({
       arrows: false,
       asNavFor: '.slider-content1',
       centerMode: true,
       slidesToShow: 5,
       speed: 1100,
       responsive: [
           {
               breakpoint: 1001,
               settings: {
                   slidesToShow: 3
               }
           },
           {
               breakpoint: 751,
               settings: {
                   slidesToShow: 2
               }
           }
       ]
   });
   ```

The problem is that the document is scrolled to slick2 when window is resized over the responsive breakpoint.

What may cause it? I definetely do not want the document to be scrolled each time I resize the window.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but if I had to take a guess or at least give you a starting point; I would say it might be an issue with the adaptiveHeight. I have a similar setup and mine is working fine. Maybe check your CSS too.

Comment: @CommonKnowledge thanks)) Actually I tried to remove adaptive height, and nothing changed about the scrolling.

Comment: does the issue still exist if you remove the responsive breakpoints?

Comment: @CommonKnowledge, no, it doesn't. Everything is OK if there are no breakpoints.

Comment: Same problem. Did anybody find a solution?